# Is there a "skip all breakpoints" command in VS(2008)?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

As title, is there a quick way to run through the code once without stopping on breakpoints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Disable All Breakpoints" from the Debug menu - you can assign a keyboard shortcut:

`Tools->Options` menu then `Environment->Keyboard`

That and of course <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> which is the default short cut for "Start Without Debugging" but I'm sure you noticed this one.

Answer (score 2):

In the debug menu, there's a "Disable all breakpoints" option that'll do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

"Start without debugging" from the Debug menu will definitely skip all breakpoints :)